# a semi colon in VS code Laravel .env file resulted in a "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated"

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

Not a question but maybe some stumbles upon this 'problem' so I wanted to share my experience.

I was just developing my Laravel application in VS Code, using Valet on a mac. I needed an extra .env variable and copy/pasted a standard link. I commited my work and worked on the api for the same project. I came back and I could not load my application in the browser. I searched the net and found different "fixes" like delete launch.json, etc..
After hours of searching: I tried to do a 'composer install' and ... the .env file failed: It contained unexpected whitespace... it was the semi colon!

TLDR;
not question, might be useful if you have the same issue

Comment: Could you perhaps turn this into a self-answered question instead? It would fit the Q&A format of this site better, as per the [tour].

Comment: @LW001 can't, only 1 reputation point at this moment! Need 15, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.